# Multiple selection in a single table using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to pull multiple rows from a single table. I'm trying to pull either all males or all females in different zip codes.

```
<?php
$zipCodes = array("55555", "66666", "77777", etc...);

$fetchUser = mysql_query("select * from users where gender = '$_POST[gender]' ".implode(" or zipCode = ", $zipCodes)." order by id desc");
while($var = mysql_fetch_array($fetchUser)) {
  code...
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.. Please explain the problem you're having..There is no question in your posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `IN` on this,

```
SELECT ...
FROM   tableName
WHERE gender = '$_POST[gender]' AND
      zipCode IN (55555, 6666, 77777)
```

currently your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Please read on **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** extension.

**[Read more on this article: Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** 
[**PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prevent SQL injection for user input
$fetchUser = mysql_query("select * from users where gender = '".filter_var($_POST[gender], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)."' OR zipCode IN (".implode(",", $zipCodes).") order by id desc");)
```